# DJANGO development server using TestCase database

Tags: python, django, django-tests, django-fixtures

**GOAL**: Run the DJANGO development server, using the TestCase database.

**Case**: DJANGO produces this database when running a TestCase. Now I'm filling the database using [DJANGO-autofixture](http://django-autofixture.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It would be really nice to start the DJANGO testserver using this database, so I can checkout how the website presents it. Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere how to do this.

Writing the test database to sqlite would make sense, but I don't see an options for this.

Any hints are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The testcase database only lives within the context of a test. It is created, migrated, and loaded with fixtures before you run your tests. Default behavior is that after your test suite runs (fail or succeed), the database is dropped.

I recommend just loading your fixtures via the `django-admin testserver yourfixture.json` command

If you really wanted to but I think it is a not a good idea.

You have the option to provide a `--keepdb` argument to your test command. This will keep your test database after your test case runs. The name of that db will your actual dbs name prefixed with `test_` You can then connect to that database via the database settings.

[test keep alive and test database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/)

[look at database settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/)

Comment: Hm Ok so maybe I should just switch to MySQL and keep the db, then run the development server using the generated tables (of course change the settings file)...?